# Java WebService Runnable Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jsp, tomcat

I am running an enterprise JSP application on Tomcat 7 that calls web services occasionally.
Over time the application develops **Runnable** Threads taking up lot of CPU cycle. These threads keep running even when application invoking them are stopped.

Here is thread dump:

```
"http-thread-598" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002ab4e8b19800 nid=0xd61 runnable [0x00002ab4fc602000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseImport(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:280)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseImport(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:656)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.model.wsdl.WSDLModel$WSDLParser.parse(WSDLModel.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parseModel(PolicyConfigParser.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parseModel(PolicyConfigParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parse(PolicyConfigParser.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1248)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:334)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at xyzservice.GetDataInterfaceHttpService.<init>(GetDataInterfaceHttpService.java:42)
    at org.xyz.PRESENTATION.gui.btHandler_getData(someClass.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3300.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:99)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:771)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:372)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    - locked <0x00000007021c13d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am having this issue randomly at 4-5 different services.

Image for CPU usage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gNl.png

Comment: That's a stack trace, not a thread dump. How do you know which threads are the ones using extra CPU? How do you know those threads _shouldn't_ be using all that CPU?

Comment: Post your thread dump and the CPU time taken by each thread, along with the code inside each run() method.

Comment: It is a thread dump taken using jstack (ref: http://qnatech.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/how-can-we-get-a-thread-dump-of-running-java-process/).

CPU time can be seen in screenshot (http://s24.postimg.org/fok2wtv39/Untitled.png). It shouldn't be using so much CPU because applications are stopped.

Comment: If you just want the threads to be stopped when application is stopped, mark the threads as 'daemon' but it will not be graceful shutdown.

Comment: Actually these threads are working abnormally even when application is running and affecting overall performance.